# PHP curl_exec not working properly

Tags: php, curl

I had a try to use the curl but the url are not executing causing the posting failure. The code are as shown.

```
$url = "www.something.com/somewhereelse.php";
$dataurl = "someparam";
$req = curl_init();
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "?DATA=$dataurl");
curl_exec($req);
```

Is there any thing wrong with my code???

Answer (score 0):

First you need to add, at least,

```
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POST, true);
```

and then you can do this, notice I removed the leading `?` It is not needed.

```
curl_setopt($req, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "DATA=$dataurl");
```

You should also be doing some error checking such as:

```
if ($ret === false || $info['http_code'] != 200) {
   $ret = "No cURL data returned for $url [". $info['http_code']. "]";
   if (curl_error($req))
     $ret .= "\n". curl_error($req);
}
curl_close($req);
echo $ret;
```

where `$ret = curl_exec($req);`

Comment: I had try the code the error shown 

No cURL data returned for www.something.com/somewhereelse.php [] Couldn't resolve host 'www.something.com/somewhereelse.php'